# Creating Netsuite printing label

Tags: html, css, netsuite

We are trying to get a 1"x4" label for Netsuite.  The right hand side of the label is our logo.

First line is part number, second line is description, and third is the barcode with the label printed date. If the description is two lines, the label looks great.  If it is only one line, the barcode gets too big and runs the date printed into the logo and can't be seen.  Our code is below.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?><!DOCTYPE pdf PUBLIC "-//big.faceless.org//report" "report-1.1.dtd">
<pdf>
  <head>
    <link name="NotoSans" type="font" subtype="truetype" src="${nsfont.NotoSans_Regular}" src-bold="${nsfont.NotoSans_Bold}" src-italic="${nsfont.NotoSans_Italic}" src-bolditalic="${nsfont.NotoSans_BoldItalic}" bytes="2" />
    <#if .locale == "zh_CN">
        <link name="NotoSansCJKsc" type="font" subtype="opentype" src="${nsfont.NotoSansCJKsc_Regular}" src-bold="${nsfont.NotoSansCJKsc_Bold}" bytes="2" />
    <#elseif .locale == "zh_TW">
        <link name="NotoSansCJKtc" type="font" subtype="opentype" src="${nsfont.NotoSansCJKtc_Regular}" src-bold="${nsfont.NotoSansCJKtc_Bold}" bytes="2" />
    <#elseif .locale == "ja_JP">
        <link name="NotoSansCJKjp" type="font" subtype="opentype" src="${nsfont.NotoSansCJKjp_Regular}" src-bold="${nsfont.NotoSansCJKjp_Bold}" bytes="2" />
    <#elseif .locale == "ko_KR">
        <link name="NotoSansCJKkr" type="font" subtype="opentype" src="${nsfont.NotoSansCJKkr_Regular}" src-bold="${nsfont.NotoSansCJKkr_Bold}" bytes="2" />
    <#elseif .locale == "th_TH">
        <link name="NotoSansThai" type="font" subtype="opentype" src="${nsfont.NotoSansThai_Regular}" src-bold="${nsfont.NotoSansThai_Bold}" bytes="2" />
    </#if>
    <style type="text/css">* {
        <#if .locale == "zh_CN">
            font-family: NotoSans, NotoSansCJKsc, sans-serif;
        <#elseif .locale == "zh_TW">
            font-family: NotoSans, NotoSansCJKtc, sans-serif;
        <#elseif .locale == "ja_JP">
            font-family: NotoSans, NotoSansCJKjp, sans-serif;
        <#elseif .locale == "ko_KR">
            font-family: NotoSans, NotoSansCJKkr, sans-serif;
        <#elseif .locale == "th_TH">
            font-family: NotoSans, NotoSansThai, sans-serif;
        <#else>
            font-family: NotoSans, sans-serif;
        </#if>
        }
        table {
            font-size: 7pt;
            margin-top: 10px;
            page-break-inside: avoid;
        }
        td p { align:left }
</style> <!--updating code as of 4-26-2023 by EDV-->
</head>
<body padding="0in 0in .0in 0.2in" size="4in x 1in">
    <#list records as label>
<table style="width: 3in; height: 1in;"><tr>
    <td align="left" style="width: 3in; height: 6px;"><span style="font-family:Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;;font-size:20px;font-weight:bold;white-space: nowrap;">${label.skuUpcBarcode?html?upper_case}</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td align="left" style="width: 3in;"><span style="font-family:Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;;font-size:12px;">${label.name}</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td align="left" style="width 3.5in"><barcode bar-width="1" codetype="code128" showtext="false" value="${label.skuUpcBarcode?html}"></barcode></td>
    <td align="center" style="height: 39px; font-size: 7pt; vertical-align: middle;">${.now?date?replace("/","")}</td>
    </tr></table>
<#if label_index % 27 == 26 && label_index != records?size - 1><pbr /><!-- Make put page break after each 27 labels (three in row, nine in columns) but not when we printed all of them --><#elseif label_index % 9 == 8 && label_index != records?size - 1><br /><!-- Make put page break after each 6 labels but not when we printed all of them --></#if></#list>
</body>
</pdf>
```

One possibility: It seems that the barcode and date are independent sections.  Is there a way to put them both on the same line?